# Python - random generated attributes for class objects - cannot 'refresh'

Tags: python

So I am creating a game where you select 5 of 10 monsters, and battle a computer's 5 monsters;

I generate random monsters (objects) within a class 'Monstercard' with completely random names and attributes using the random function;

Everything runs perfectly, and I end up with 20 monsters (10 for player, 10 for opponent) - the objects are referenced in two lists respectively

```
playerinv = [list of names of Monster objects (e.g. playermon1)]
oppinv = [list of names of Monster objects]
```

So far everything works perfectly, however, I then want an option to 'refresh' the monsters assigned to either the player or the computer.

I assumed I could just run a new defined function that both deletes the objects, clears the (inventory) lists and then copy/paste the code I used to generate the monsters originally.

However, when I do this, and view the objects/inventory, the names, stats etc are all the same.

What am I missing?! [If I close game and restart it, I get different starting monsters and ratings every time, so the original generation code seems fine]

Extracts below:

example of class setup:

```
class Monstercard:
    def __init__(self,monstername, type, hp, attack,defence,armour,armourp,siphon,special1,special2,special3,
                 slot1,slot2,slot3,armoure,weapon,weapon2,rating):
        self.mname = monstername
        self.type = type
        self.hp = hp
        self.att = attack
        self.deef = defence
        self.arm = armour
        self.armp = armourp
        self.siph = siphon
        self.spec1 = special1
        self.spec2 = special2
        self.spec3 = special3
        self.slot1 = slot1
        self.slot2 = slot2
        self.slot3 = slot3
        self.arme = armoure
        self.weap = weapon
        self.weap2 = weapon2
        self.rating = rating
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(repr(self.mname))
```

example of random generator (only pasted 1 of the monsters being generated):

```
def createplayerinvenory():
    global playermonname
    global playerinv
    global playermon1, playermon2, playermon3, playermon4, playermon5, playermon6, playermon7, playermon8, playermon9
    global playermon10
    global pm1r, pm2r, pm3r, pm4r, pm5r, pm6r, pm7r, pm8r, pm9r, pm10r
    global pm1ri, pm2ri, pm3ri, pm4ri, pm5ri, pm6ri, pm7ri, pm8ri, pm9ri, pm10ri
    playerinv.clear()
    playermonname.clear()
    for x in range(0,10):
        a = random.randint(1,6)
        if a == 1:
            ng = str(random.choice(jnl1))+str(random.choice(jnl2))+" the "+str(random.choice(name1))+ \
                 " "+str(random.choice(name2))
            playermonname.append(str(ng))
        if a == 2:
            ng = str(random.choice(jnl1))+str(random.choice(jnl2))
            playermonname.append(str(ng))
        if a == 3:
            ng = str(random.choice(jnl1))+str(random.choice(jnl2))+" "+str(random.choice(jns1))
            playermonname.append(str(ng))
        if a == 4:
            ng = str(random.choice(jnl1))+str(random.choice(jnl2))+" the "+str(random.choice(name1))
            playermonname.append(str(ng))
        if a == 5:
            ng = str(random.choice(jnl1))+str(random.choice(jnl2))+" the "+str(random.choice(name2))
            playermonname.append(str(ng))
        if a == 6:
            ng = str(random.choice(name1))+" "+str(random.choice(name2))
            playermonname.append(str(ng))

    playermon1 = Monstercard(playermonname[0],"normal",random.randint(1000,10000),random.randint(100,1000),
                             random.randint(25,850),random.randint(0,75),random.randint(0,60),0)
```

start of code to delete entries before refreshing with newly generated monsters:
I use same globals as before: and add:

```
playerinv.clear()
del(playermon1)
del(playermonname)
```

Here is the full code, but reduced for only 2 monsters:

```
def createplayerinvenory():
    global playermonname
    global playerinv
    global playermon1, playermon2, playermon3, playermon4, playermon5, playermon6, playermon7, playermon8, playermon9
    global playermon10
    global pm1r, pm2r, pm3r, pm4r, pm5r, pm6r, pm7r, pm8r, pm9r, pm10r
    global pm1ri, pm2ri, pm3ri, pm4ri, pm5ri, pm6ri, pm7ri, pm8ri, pm9ri, pm10ri
    playerinv.clear()
    playermonname.clear()
    for x in range(0,2):
        a = random.randint(1,6)
        if a == 1:
            ng = str(random.choice(jnl1))+str(random.choice(jnl2))+" the "+str(random.choice(name1))+ \
                 " "+str(random.choice(name2))
            playermonname.append(str(ng))
        if a == 2:
            ng = str(random.choice(jnl1))+str(random.choice(jnl2))
            playermonname.append(str(ng))
        if a == 3:
            ng = str(random.choice(jnl1))+str(random.choice(jnl2))+" "+str(random.choice(jns1))
            playermonname.append(str(ng))
        if a == 4:
            ng = str(random.choice(jnl1))+str(random.choice(jnl2))+" the "+str(random.choice(name1))
            playermonname.append(str(ng))
        if a == 5:
            ng = str(random.choice(jnl1))+str(random.choice(jnl2))+" the "+str(random.choice(name2))
            playermonname.append(str(ng))
        if a == 6:
            ng = str(random.choice(name1))+" "+str(random.choice(name2))
            playermonname.append(str(ng))

    playermon1 = Monstercard(playermonname[0],"normal",random.randint(1000,10000),random.randint(100,1000),
                             random.randint(25,850),random.randint(0,75),random.randint(0,60),
                             random.randint(0,35),'none','none','none','none','none','none','none','none','none',0)
    playermon2 = Monstercard(playermonname[1],"normal",random.randint(1000,10000),random.randint(100,1000),
                             random.randint(25,850),random.randint(0,75),random.randint(0,60),
                             random.randint(0,35),'none','none','none','none','none','none','none','none','none',0)

    pm1ri = int((((playermon1.hp / 10000 * 100) + (playermon1.att / 1000 * 100) + (playermon1.deef / 850 * 100) +
                  (playermon1.arm / 75 * 100) + (playermon1.arm / 60 * 100) + (playermon1.siph / 35 * 100)) / 6))
    pm2ri = int((((playermon2.hp / 10000 * 100) + (playermon2.att / 1000 * 100) + (playermon2.deef / 850 * 100) +
                  (playermon2.arm / 75 * 100) + (playermon2.arm / 60 * 100) + (playermon2.siph / 35 * 100)) / 6))
    playermon1.rating = pm1ri
    playermon2.rating = pm2ri
    playerinv = [playermon1, playermon2]
```

Comment: Where is the code that adds monsters to `playerinv` and `oppinv`?

Comment: If you created the inventories with `playerinv = [playermon1, playermon2, ...]`, reassigning  the `playermonX` variables won't change the list. You need to rebuild the list itself with the new variable values.

Comment: A to Q1 - I built the list of playerinv and oppinv with a codeline: playerinv = [playermon1, playermon2...]

Comment: And did you do that again after refreshing? You need to.

Comment: None of the code you posted seems to be relevant to the question. Show the code that refreshes.

Comment: A to Q2 - yes that is how I built the list, i have tried del(playerinv) (and playerinv.clear() )and creating it again (albeit with same name) but that doesn't work either

Comment: To refresh the inventory, I run the same code, together with playerinv.clear()
del(playermon1)
del(playermonname) before the generation

Comment: If you reassign the variable, it shouldn't contain the old value. You're not reassigning something.

Comment: There's no need to `del` anything.

Comment: All those `playermonX` variables are a code smell. You should use a loop, not repeat the same code with a different variable name.

Comment: I added the full code. I am only in my second/third week tinkering with python in my spare time, am just about to work out how to generate a list of objects in a better way...in any event the playerinv.clear should remove them, and the rest of the code should replace their attributes - or not?

Comment: @Barmar really appreciate you taking the time to respond! I think I worked out a way in the meantime to better generate the monsters without assigning variable names, but not sure it fixes my issue stated above

Comment: I don't see any way that this could be leaving the old value of `playerinv` if you're calling `createplayerinvenory()` when you refresh.

Comment: There's no need for `playerinv.clear()` `del(playermon1)` `del(playermonname)` since the function reassigns all these variables.